# WebRequest returns Bad Request 400 but URL works fine in browser

Tags: linux, vb.net, clickonce

I'm having a problem with a ClickOnce application not updating.  It's returning a bad request 400 when trying to download the .application file.  In looking into it, I think it may be something with the server.  As a test, I tried creating a WebRequest in a vb.net program:

```
Dim request As Net.WebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create("http://pacificagronomics.com/top.gif")
```

request.GetResponse() returns the same bad request 400 error; however, http://pacificagronomics.com/top.gif works just fine.  The application has been working for years but suddenly isn't. Is there some server setting that needs to be changed?  It's a Linux server and I've checked case issues.

Comment: FYI: I'm getting the same thing from here...

Comment: At least it isn't just me.

Comment: A little more info.  The WebExceptionStatus thrown is ProtocolError

Comment: And even more.  It's on a Network Solutions server.  If anyone knows of changes they made recently, that would help.

Comment: Time to give the I.T. guys a call me thinks...

Comment: Ok, They added something so that you have to put in a UserAgent ie request.UserAgent= ".NET Framework Test Client".  Now, to figure out how to put that in the ClickOnce

Comment: If anyone is still looking at this, I finally got something from Microsoft.  Their official response is "The cause of this failure is the new security setting of the server, but at this time don't have immediate plans to make the change. We will consider this as a feature request for a future release."

Comment: LOL Typical Microsoft answer. Yes we know we broke it, but until enough people complain about it we don't care....

Comment: Yeah, no kidding.  I read somewhere that if you're in Thailand, you're completely screwed.  Somehow, they've applied whatever Network Solutions did to every server .  I just hope they actually do something before other providers here follow NS.  I should probably look into some other way to distribute applications but ClickOnce is really convenient.

Comment: Yup that's why many IT departments have a strict NO UPDATES policy on their servers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the right URL to HttpWebRequest?

Make sure the url parameters are correct.

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
```

Try passing in a simple URL to check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and Joe's comment above fixed it for me.
I needed to add a User-Agent header to the request and then it stopped returning a 400 error:

```
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.UserAgent = "SomeClient/1.0";
```